# Customize List as Cards

Tags: react-admin

I would like to customize rows as cards (see picture).
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/99944/52724861-6c588180-2fb0-11e9-97fa-bf8ab8f4026b.png

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault, in the doc I found the anser:

[Using a Custom Iterator](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-list-component)